# How to check if a thread is alive in java application, without having access to the object?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

In a java application, is there a way to check if a thread is still running from a different place than where the thread has started?

I have a certain thread running somewhere in java application. How can I check the status of that thread pool. I have the name for that certain thread.

Comment: You have much bigger problems if you have to check if your threads are still alive.

Comment: I need to check status of those threads, if the thread has stopped for some reason, I need to perform actions based on that result

Comment: If your threads are stopping "for some reason", find that reason and fix the real problem.

Comment: They should not stop ideally, but I need a check to fix if the problem has arised.

Answer (score 2):

`yourThread.isAlive()` returns if the thread is alive and has not yet died.

Also `yourThread.getState()`gives you the state of the thread.

'...if the thread has stopped for some reason, I need to perform actions based on that result...' so your thread stops for some reason with nothing abnormal happens and if it was an exception you could catch it in `try-catch` block:

```
try{
}
catch(Exception e){
}
```

There might be an error or something else. Try to use this to catch it:

```
try {
    // your tasks
} catch (Throwable e) {
   // ...I need to perform actions based on that result...
}
```

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such errors are abnormal conditions. ...
>
> An instance of ThreadDeath is thrown in the victim thread when the (deprecated) Thread.stop() method is invoked.
>
> The top-level error handler does not print out a message if ThreadDeath is never caught.
>
> The class ThreadDeath is specifically a subclass of Error rather than Exception, even though it is a "normal occurrence", because many applications catch all occurrences of Exception and then discard the exception.

[Class ThreadDeath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadDeath.html)

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.isAlive()` helps you to check if it is alive.

`Thread.getState()` will help you to get the exact state it is in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use monitoring tools which are shipped with jdk like `jstack`, `jconsole` to check status of running threads. Alternatively you can take thread dump and check running thread status. On Linux you can do something like this `kill -3 pId` where pId is your java process running id.